# python: Adding numpy array and color with boolean array mask

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have a numpy array 3d rgb `image` of size `(500,500,3)`, a boolean `mask` array of size `(500, 500)`, and an rgb `color` array of size `(3,)`.  I want to replace the pixels on my numpy array `image` where my `mask` array is `True` at that index and replace it with my `color` pixel.

Comment: `image[mask] = color`?

Comment: @Divakar that worked.  I didn't think it would, because the mask is not an array of indices.  I didn't realize you could do that.  Thanks!

Comment: Magic of giving it a try huh!

Comment: lol, I guess so!